# How do i select sibling Elements in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I got a 4-5 rows of div ... when i click on any row it should change the selected one and color it as red and rest all to black ... i am using below logic but not working for me giving error as angular.min.js:117 TypeError: angular.element(...).siblings is not a function

Do i need to include jQuery file?
Can i do it without including jQuery file?

plz help

```js
$scope.divClick = function($event){
  console.log($event.target);
  
        /* below siblings function not working for me*/
  angular.element(event.target).siblings().css('color','black');
  
  
  angular.element(event.target).css('color','red');
 };
```

```html
<div ng-controller="homeController">
<h1>Welcome</h1>

<div ng-repeat="x in json" ng-click="divClick($event)">
Name: {{x.Name}}<br/> City: {{x.City}}<br/> Country: {{x.Country}}<br/><br/>
</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your default color to be black.

```
   <div ng-repeat="x in json" ng-class="{setRed: $index == value}" ng-click="divClick($index)">
```

Give CSS style to your class setRed.

Your controller function:

```
$scope.divClick = function(index){
    $scope.value = index;
};
```

Comment: The login is very simple. The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index is set to the item index or key. So on every click(ng-click) you set the $scope.value equal to the index of item just clicked. Now ng-class iterates for each $index, checking if it is equal to the update $scope.value. If it comes out to be equal then SetRed class is applied on the division.

Comment: what is the difference between $index and index .... i tried using both $index and index ... both worked for me .... i have seen same scenario for $event and event

Comment: I am not sure how it worked for you, it didnt for me. Ideally it should not work because $index is a property of ng-repeat. If you write divClick(index) in place if divClick($index) then it will look for $scope.index variable which doesnot exist hence resulting in an error divClick(index) not defined.

Comment: Please refer this page for understanding the properties of ng-repeat: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat]
Refer this page for understanding ng-class : [https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass]

Comment: $scope.divClick = function($index){
     $scope.value = $index;
 };

Comment: thing worked for me ... i wrote $index instead of index

Comment: When you write $scope.foo = function(param) {...} then the name of the param could be anything(just make sure to avoid conflicts). $scope.divClick = function($index){ $scope.value = $index; }; means that you are saying you have a parameter by the name '$index'. Here index does not refer to the property of ng-repeat. This defination is same as $scope.divClick = function(param){ $scope.value = param; };

Answer (score 1):

In general it's bad idea to modify DOM right from your controllers.
It's better to use scope or model properties and make decisions what class to apply based on them.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in json" ng-click="select($index)" ng-class="{'selected': $index == selectedIndex}">
Name: {{x.Name}}<br/>
City: {{x.City}}
```

Then you just have to update selectedIndex in you click handler

```
$scope.select = function(x) {
   $scope.selectedIndex = x;
};
```

Fully working solution is here

https://jsfiddle.net/kvtcw8y6/4/

Other way is to have `isSelected` property on you model and update it accordingly.